# G is $k_{S}$-saturated and has more than $ng(n)$ edges. I need to prove that at least $n-g(n)$ vertices of $G$ have degrees more than $g(n)$

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a $K_{s}$-saturated graph. Suppose it has more than $ng(n)$ edges. I need to prove that at least $n-g(n)$ vertices of $G$ have degrees more than $g(n)$.

Tried proving it through contradiction and using the rule that $\sum_{v \in G}{d(v)}=2e(G)$ but got nowhere.

P.S: $g(n)$ has to do with $O(log n)$ in the given. I don't know if I need this. This is mentioned in the paper Minimizing the Numbers of Cliques and Cycles of Fixed Size in an F-saturated Graph by Debsoumya Chakraborti and Po-Shen Loh.